# Remove the only single column from datatable and insert it into a generic list of strings c#

Tags: c#, sql

here is my method

```
    public virtual List<String> GetJobName(Nullable<int> id, Nullable<int> userID)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

        var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
            new SqlParameter("id", id) :
            new SqlParameter("id", typeof(int));
        parameters.Add(idParameter);

        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new SqlParameter("userID", userID) :
            new SqlParameter("userID", typeof(int));
        parameters.Add(userIDParameter);


        table = ExecuteSPDataTable("GetJobName", parameters, out list);
      //  DataFiller<String> j = new DataFiller<String>();
      //  List<String> rows = j.FromDataTableToList(table);

    }
```

Table holds one value, the single job and i want to put that single string into a `list<string>` and return.

Any help?

Comment: Where is `list` defined?

Comment: You haven't given much information

Comment: Some more details would be good.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable table is just a string, and you simply want to return that string as a list of string, then all you have to do is this:

```
return new List<string>{ table };
```